# @RequestMapping Doesn't work- Did not find handler method

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, servlets

I have problem in getting the *@RequestMapping* to work, I get the following logs; could you please help me understand the log?

Log while booting:

> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name  'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/ruler/webjars/test]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /webjars/test
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find handler method for [/webjars/test]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for  request [/webjars/test] are [/webjars/**, /**]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for request [/webjars/test] are {}
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/webjars/test] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/webjars/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@52454457]]] and 1 interceptor
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for [/ruler/webjars/test] is: -1
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request

Log while accessing *localhost:80/ruler/test*:

> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name
>   'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/ruler/test]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler
>   method for path /test
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Did not find
>   handler method for [/test]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Matching patterns for
>   request [/test] are [/**]
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - URI Template variables for
>   request [/test] are {}
>
> DEBUG o.s.w.s.h.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping - Mapping [/test] to
>   HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler
>   [locations=[class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path
>   resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path
>   resource [public/], ServletContext resource [/]],
>   resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@4538856f]]]
>   and 1 interceptor
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Last-Modified value for
>   [/ruler/test] is: -1
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned
>   to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming
>   HandlerAdapter completed request handling
>
> DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed
>   request

Application.properties:

```
server.servlet.context-path=/ruler
server.port=80
```

RestController:

```
    @RestController
public class myController {
    private final MedicalService medicalService;

    @Autowired
    public myController(MedicalService medicalService) {
        this.medicalService = medicalService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/test")
    public String testRest()
    {
        return "Yay";
    }
}
```

No web.xml.

Comment: 1. show your complete controller class or atleast class declaration and annotations 2. how are you calling this endpoint and what is the url u r using?

Comment: Try addin the `@ResponseBody` annotation to your `testRest` method

Comment: @S.Tushinov That is not beneficial, according to documents; using `@RestController` is equivalent of using `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`

Comment: Shouldn't you be accessing the url along with the port-number? Something like `localhost:8080/ruler/test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48959801/1977429), it was because of project structure, not the configs.

App package should be like `com.app` then controller would be `com.app.controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Also You can use @GetMapping with ResponseEntity for more specific information

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> testRest(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Yay");
    }
```

Comment: I added the logs in the question itself; it simply says it doesn't find any mapping!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test")
```

to

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

Comment: I supposed that this could have solved the problem because his request is a GET request and the handler couldn't find the mapping for it, however as Ace discussed in his own answer the problem was coming from a different cause.

Comment: Please specify why this should solve the problem. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers